# How to star pictures so that only starred can be exported/copied?

Tags: windows, file-management, photos

What is an ideal system for starring nice photos that enables to select only the starred pictures in Explorer or other programs?

E.g., any software stack where user can go through 2k photos, select good ones and the star is saved in a smart way that can be recognized in Explorer.

Do not suggest modifying file name since this is too many clicks in any Picasa-like management program.

Note:
Suppose a user wants to export only high quality pictures to a tablet. E.g., with a batch size convert utility like FastStore resizer or just simple default file Explorer.

The OP is NOT looking for a particular software (single program) but for architectural solution.

E.g., one solution is to add to file name e.g., qqq for 3 star picture and qq for a 2 star picture. Then, the user can select to copy only pictures with 3 or more stars with mask *qqq*.jpg

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for photo/image management software that can modify the **Rating** property/metadata of images so that you can later view it via an Explorer column and easily sort/select images? Also, does it *have* to be done via **Rating**? Can't you use the management software to directly compare/rate/copy images? Finally, which version of Windows?

Comment: win xp and higher. Either rating (1-5 stars) or just star/nostar status. It can be done via any mean. The best is file name since all programs will support that. The key part is ability to select out of 5000 pics in 280 folders only those with stars and end up with only 1589 starred pics in 273 folders (in a single operation, not 273 manual steps).

Comment: I think Raymond Chen read your mind. :) [How can I write a script that finds my top-rated photos?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/14/10384593.aspx) As for rating the images, [FastPictureViewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com), while not free, fully supports [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) rating tags.

Comment: just reporting back my findings: XnViewMP beta ver0.53 can read XMP and Exif rating tag and writes rating into the photo file directly.